# Civilization V on OSX is very very slow

Tags: civilization-5, macos

I'm trying to play Civilization V on OSX. I have an i7 2.8 GHz and 8 GB of memory but it is very slow.

My mate told me that this is because the game was written in Logo running on a Sinclair ZX80 emulator.

Are there any settings I can change to speed it up?

Comment: Do you mean 8 **GB** of RAM? Also, how fast is your video card? According to the Wiki, these are the requirements for OSX: 
 Mac OS 10.6.4 (Snow Leopard), 2.6 GHz Quad Core Processor, 4 GB RAM, Video Memory: 512 MB


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_V

Comment: Also, your mate is joking. [This is a ZX80.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinclair_ZX80)

Comment: @mfc are you on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fellow Apple user I can tel that Aspyr (company who ports some game on Mac and ported Civ V) don't do awesome job.

What you can do;

- Turn on your **Activity Monitor** check and close programs who use a lot of RAM (Google Chrome and Mail are first to go)
- [Use purge command](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/24/free-up-inactive-memory-in-mac-os-x-with-purge-command/) to find out more **free RAM** before opening game or download something that do that for you for example [FreeMemory](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/freememory/id460931672?mt=12)
- Use this FreeMemory or else app
- Want to be sure that game performance will be the best? Turn on game **without any active app** in your dock
- Still don't happy with your ram? Turn on and off your Mac again.
- Change and lock your [Energy Saver](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2412) settings in your preference panel to "**better graphics**" (disable automatic changes)
- After turning on game. Go to settings first and **change resolution on one grade lower 16:10 resolution** (for example I have 1680:1050 and mostly I play 1440:900)
- Good graphics? Who need them! **Set all as low or disable**.
- Turn on game! Yay. It will should work great.
- Now change one or two graphic settings on better. Go back to game...
- Still it is working great? Try again!

Hope that this will help you find your optimal game performance.

Comment: I agree with you, the port by Aspry was atrocious. I have an 27 inch iMac with the top end video card that Apple could supply, by dumbing down the screen resolution I may as well run it in a ZX80!

Answer (score 2):

Civilization 5 also lets you do away with the fancy 3d graphics altogether and play on a 2d map with abstract representations of units and whatnot. It's called "strategic view". All you have to do to activate it is push the F10 key on your keyboard.

Personally, I prefer it over the graphics-heavy 3D mode.

Comment: I think this answer will be significantly more useful if you actually state the steps needed to activate this 2D mode

Comment: I know. :( I don't currently have it installed and have been busy.

Comment: Press Fn + F10. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

The graphics changes are bottom right box but left side and outside the box that says “a unit needs orders.” It looks like a scroll or a set of hexes in a round button. Try them and see what you get.

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're talking about with only words. A picture would highly benefit this answer.